# How to replace text to URL from paragraph

Tags: php

I have some variables:

```
$string = 'he says of stackoverflow.com, & http://google.com, the website he founded in 2001'
$string = 'he says of www.stackoverflow.com & http://www.google.com the website he founded in 2001'
```

Now I want to replace with the URL's to a HTML link

I am using preg_replace funtion:

```
echo preg_replace("#http://([\S]+?)#Uis", '<a href="http://\\1">\\1</a>', $string2);
```

This code only replace the http://-url's to a link.
Also if there is a comma after .com (like for example `http://google.com,`), this comma needs be in the link as well: `<a href="http://www.google.com,">`

Please tell me how I could archieve this.

Comment: Are you sure you want the comma to be part of the url? Regularly it should be _excluded_, just like a trailing point (as in normal writing language, you would append a comma or a point as interpunction, not as part of an url).

Comment: preg_replace already convert and use comma after com, but i don't want to convert comma

Answer (score 0):

You need to enhance you're regex pattern to match url without http:// and www. as well. However there still is a problem, as distinguishing arbitrary character-sequences which contain a dot from valid urls is complicated.

The following pattern should suite your needs:

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?((?:www\.)?([\w\.\-]){2,}\.[a-z,]{2,5}(:?\?[\w=#,-]+)?)
```

http://regexr.com/3b4ov